# Cursor: none not working and custom cursor not showing in pngs/gifs

Tags: html

So im trying to add a custom cursor to my website but it doesn't show up when I point at pngs and gifs in my website. help

```
.body{
    height: 100vh;
    cursor: none;
}
.cursor{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute;

}
```

[image of the the prblm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tn4R.png)

Comment: You're going to have to include more information than that.  No one can help you without the pertinent code.

Comment: comment from @D-Waqas - "As in, does the cursor disappear? Can you please post the code as well; there is not enough detail in your question."

Comment: i have edited the quesiotn pls see

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to understand without looking your HTML but try adding `.body:hover{cursor:none}`